# Why wasn't the Black Widow destroyed by the four Infinity Stones she held in Widow’s Run?

Tags: marvel, infinity-stones, black-widow, avengers-assemble-tv

In *Avengers Assemble* season 2 episode 12, *Widow's Run*, Natasha holds four Infinity Stones to defeat Dormammu (that series is actually great, btw).

[image: Natasha wielding four Infinity Stones in the episode “Widow’s Run”]

How was she able to do that, if only highly powerful beings in the MCU could bear those, like Thanos, Loki (only one on his scepter) and the assembled Guardians of the Galaxy (but only a single stone)?

Was it her "*discipline of the mind*" as Thor puts it? Is Russian spy academy training *that* powerful, or is there something else to it?

Comment: It's not MCU work, and even there, it was different then people think. Only what was contained in the center of the *Orb* (*later* isolated in the form of the Power Stone) was actually shown shown to destroy *just one person* for reasons unsure. Better forget stupid Ego talk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although this series was inspired by the [first MCU *Avengers* film](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Avengers), it isn't set within the MCU. Instead, it's apparently set in the same universe as the [*Ultimate Spider-Man* animated series](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man_(Animated_Series)), which was designated [Earth-12041](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-12041) in *[Secret Wars: Official Guide to the Marvel Multiverse #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Wars:_Official_Guide_to_the_Marvel_Multiverse_Vol_1_1)*.

Since it isn't set within the MCU, the Infinity Stones in this series can be somewhat different from the ones in the MCU. They're clearly not exactly the same, as these stones speak to people around them, attempting to seduce and corrupt them, which doesn't apply in the MCU.

Also, these Infinity Stones don't have the same colour designations as the ones in the MCU. In *[Avengers Assemble](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Assemble_(TV_Series))* S02E13, we see Thanos using individual stones, and the Time Stone is shown to be orange in this universe, whereas [it's green in the MCU](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Stone). The Mind Stone is shown to be blue in this universe, whereas [it's yellow in the MCU](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_Stone). And the Space Stone is shown to be purple in this universe, whereas [it's blue in the MCU](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Stone).

In the universe the mainline comics are set it -- [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) -- the Infinity Stones (or Infinity Gems, as they're also called in the comics) aren't portrayed as being directly harmful to the wielder, the  way they are in the MCU. For example, in *[She-Hulk Vol. 1 #12](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/She-Hulk_Vol_1_12)*, She-Hulk was able to wield the Power Gem in her human form, Jennifer Walters, without feeling any pain or sustaining any injury.

> [image]
>
> <sub>*She-Hulk Vol. 1 #12* (April, 2005)</sub>

It seems likely then that the Infinity Stones in the *Avengers Assemble* animated series take after the ones in the comics, in this respect, rather than the ones in the MCU. Natasha's S.H.I.E.L.D. training was given as the reason that she could resist the stones' corrupting influence, but it doesn't make sense to think that this would also allow her to resist being *physically* harmed by the stones.

> WIDOW: Hulk, these stones. They corrupted Tony and they'll do the same to anyone who comes in contact with them.
>
> HULK: Yeah, like you.
>
> WIDOW: No. **My S.H.I.E.L.D. training can keep the stones from taking over my mind, but not for long.**
>
> <sub>*Avengers Assemble* - S02E12 - "[Widow's Run](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=599&t=25988)"</sub>

Comment: The soul stone is also missing. Besides, there's a lot of inconsistency in this show. Captain America nearly died grabbing the power stone on episode 1 of season 2 (and the wave of energy it unleashed destroyed all the robots that even Hulk had trouble smashing). Another scene at the beginning of season 2 depicts Hulk struggling to grab the power stone and feed it into a robot (because it's too powerful). Later on, Dr. Spectrum is shown to struggle using the reality stone to alter reality, to the point he requires a device to help him. Then Black Widow uses 4 stones without straining at all.

Comment: This video is a bit glitchy, but it's the aforementioned scene with Captain nearly dying: https://youtu.be/IjPUNKrIa9c?t=63

Comment: A great answer nonetheless... many Earths to be considered, makes me think a lot about many weirds things... Is there's an Earth where the stones are powerless? Is there's an Earth that has been destroyed as soon as a stone arrived here? So much to consider...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, a possible answer to this question is: inconsistency.

In the very first episode of Season 2, titled *[The Arsenal](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/The_Arsenal)*, Red Skull arrives on Earth with the Power Stone. While the Avengers are busying themselves fighting robots, Captain America attempts to pick up the stone. Because of its power, he was visibly struggling to hold it, and its unleashed power destroyed all the surrounding robots (although Hawkeye somehow managed to survive by taking cover behind a tiny rock). After he managed to release it, Black Widow attempted to grab it, but he stopped her, commenting that it's too powerful.

Here's an excerpt of that scene, although part of it is cut off:

At the end of the episode, Hulk can be seen grabbing it to put it inside a robot named Arsenal to turn it on. Although he wasn't as badly affected as Captain America, he was visibly struggling, judging by all the veins appearing over his body:

Here's a screenshot just in case:

[image: Hulk is visibly struggling to hold the Power Stone. The veins are visible all over his left arm to his neck, and he's gritting his teeth to endure the pain.]

Later on, in episode 9, titled *[The Dark Avengers](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dark_Avengers)*, [Doctor Spectrum](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Spectrum) from the [Squadron Supreme](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/Squadron_Supreme) used the Reality Stone to alter reality. They attempted to erase the Avengers from existence and make themselves as the hero of Earth. Except all they managed to do was turning the Avengers into supervillain, because the stone is too powerful and Doctor Spectrum cannot fully control it.
At the end of the episode, he attempted to use a device to amplify his control over the stone. But the Captain was the one who ended up using it to restore reality. And when the Captain grabbed the stone, he seemed to show some level of discomfort, although not as much as when he grabbed the Power Stone:

But as you pointed out, somehow Black Widow is capable of just pick up 4 stones and use them without breaking a sweat. For some reasons, they either forgot about the others struggling to even grab/use the stones, or they decided to give up on the idea without giving any further explanation.

Comment: But then again, S2E2 has the Avengers struggling to fight against Thanos without any stone, and S2E13 has them taking him out nearly instantly.

Comment: One episode had MODOK use the Mind Stone to control the shield and try to arrest the Avengers. In the process, an accident happened and it switched their bodies, while MODOK was trying to unleash the full potential of the stone. In another, Loki was using the power of the Space Stone, hidden inside his stone necklace. And then you have Iron Man who was slowly unbirthing because the stone stuck inside his reactor was making him younger. But that's not as notable as these two examples.